# Removing Empty Lines of a list in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My goal is to get a simple text output like:

> ```
> https://widget.reviews.io/rating-snippet/dist.js
> ```

But I keep getting output like this:

> ```
> https://widget.reviews.io/rating-snippet/dist.js
> ```

All these empty lines are the problem
--> Before there where [] but I removed them with `''.join`

Now I only have these empty lines.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.nutrimuscle.com")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

# Find all script tags
for n in soup.find_all('script'):

    # Check if the src attribute exists, and if it does grab the source URL
    if 'src' in n.attrs:
        javascript = n['src']

    # Otherwise assume that the javascript is contained within the tags
    else:
        javascript = ''


    kameleoonRegex = re.compile(r'[\w].*rating-snippet/dist.js')
    #Everything I tried :D
    kameleeonScript = kameleoonRegex.findall(javascript)
    text = ''.join(kameleeonScript)
    print(text)
```

It's probably not that hard but I've been on this for hours

Comment: Use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) or [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)?

Comment: Adjusted the last line to ```print(text.strip())``` but still same output

Comment: What does `print(repr(text))` show?

Comment: It shows:
''
''
''
'https://widget.reviews.io/rating-snippet/dist.js'
''
''
''
''
all in new lines

Comment: Okay, that happens because there are other `<script>` tags that do not match your regex. You want to make sure your regex matched something before trying to print it. `if kameleeonScript: print(kameleeonScript[0])`, and you can get rid of the `join`. You might find it helpful to go through a tutorial on lists, as well as these links: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if kameleeonScript: print(kameleeonScript[0])
```

did the job :)